# Facebook share isnt reading any meta og tags

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, share

my facebook share isnt reading any of my meta tags. The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '924796707731406',
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.1'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.1';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<meta property="og:image" content="https://@Context.Request.Host/img/OppaFb.png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200px" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630px" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="OPPA - უნივერსალური ელექტრონული საფულე" />
<meta property="og:description" content="ოპპა  ფულის მარტივად მართვაში გეხმარება. საიმედოდ დაცულ სივრცეში შეგიძლია გადაიხადო, გადარიცხო და დააგროვო ფული" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="924796707731406"/>

<script>
document.getElementById('piggy-bank-fb-shear-btn').onclick = function () {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        app_id: '924796707731406',
        href: window.fbSheareUrl,
    }, function (response) { });
}</script>
```

Comment: I assume all of this is in `<head>`? Have you sent your page through this yet? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: yes I did and I got Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Missing Properties
The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id
Could Not Connect To Server
Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers.

Answer (score 2):

Try using Facebooks "Sharing Debugger" [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

If I am correct this is for the **www.oppa.ge** website. And by using the debugger and looking at the html on the url it seems these tags missing...

`og:url`, `og:type`, `fb:app_id`

[Results here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.oppa.ge)

Also this could be due to your app on Facebook being "Misconfigured".

I get this error

> Misconfigured App
>
> Sorry, oppa-share hasn't been approved for display in App Center.

When doing the following

1. Going to `https://graph.facebook.com/{APP_ID_HERE}` (https://graph.facebook.com/924796707731406)
2. Follow the "link" attribute in the JSON (https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=924796707731406)

Comment: share is on a different link http://test.oppa.ge/piggybank/1002392 I ran it in "Sharing Debugger".

Comment: @GeorgeKrialashvili that one doesn’t even load in my browser, and an online ping service such as https://ping.eu/ping/ reports 100% packet loss ... something does not seem right with your server setup.